# How to use react-redux connect in a monorepo

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm adding redux to an expo react native calendar app that's uses components shared in a monorepo.

Here's the basic directory structure:

```
app/
   web/
      Day.web.js
   shared/
      DayComponent.js
   mobile/
      App.js
      Day.native.js
```

This is a big simplification, but basically, my web and mobile apps call shared/DayComponent which houses a lot of common business logic, which calls either web/ or mobile/Day.js components (which house purely view logic).

When I try to run react-redux's `connect` inside shared/DayComponent.js, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered a solution by trial error, found no articles or tutorials on this subject.

For a reason I don't fully understand, `connect` doesn't want to be called from a module outside the submodule(in this case mobile)'s main directory.

Inside the mobile directory, I made a file called connect.js with nothing but:

```js
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export default function mobileConnect(...args){
    return connect(...args)
}
```

Then, instead of importing directly from inside shared/DayComponent.js, I imported `connect` from this file.